# Yii AR, select related tables with condition

Tags: activerecord, yii

```
$projects = Project::model()->with(array(
    'pvotes' => array(
          'condition'=>'pvotes.user_id='.Yii::app()->user->id,
    ),
))->findAllByAttributes(array(
    'status' => array('register','vote','selected'),
));
```

I want to select all `projects` where "'status' => array('register','vote','selected')" with `pvotes` where "user_id='.Yii::app()->user->id". But this code selects `projects` where "pvotes.user_id='.Yii::app()->user->id" and "'status' => array('register','vote','selected')"..

Project:

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'pvotes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProjectVote', 'project_id'),
        );
    }
```

ProjectVote:

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'project' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Project', 'project_id'),
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        );
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you add with() with condition, it will limit the search result,

if you just need projects in those status, then use with without array, just the string `model()->with('pvotes')->`

and just use conditions to limit your Projects